# Retrieving the child node value from XML using PHP

Tags: php, xml

```
   <Property>
      <Name>TaskId</Name>
      <Value>12345</Value>
   </Property>

   <Property>
      <Name>TaskName</Name>
      <Value>Task1</Value>
   </Property>

   <Property>
      <Name>TaskId</Name>
      <Value>6789</Value>
   </Property>

   <Property>
      <Name>TaskName</Name>
      <Value>Task2</Value>
   </Property>
```

Could anyone help me how I can retrieve all the taskID ?

Desired Output:
12345 
6789

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything?  If not, check out [the manual](http://www.php.net//manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)

Comment: Yes many people here can help you, but atleast take the first step yourself and write some code :)

Comment: $nameNodeList = $doc->getElementsByTagName('Name');

foreach ($nameNodeList as $nameNode) {

    $name     = $nameNode->getFirstChild->getNodeValue;<br/>
        $parNode = $nameNode->getParentNode;
        $valueNode = $parNode->getElementsByTagName('Value')->item(0);
        if (~isempty($valueNode))
  {
   if ($valueNode.hasChildNodes)
   {
   $value     = $valueNode->getFirstChild->getNodeValue;
                echo $name.$value;
            }
        }
}

Comment: Problem with adding in new line. Sorry for the inconvenience. I am new here.

Comment: @user3752642: You can edit your question, put the code from the comment into your question, then it's much more clear. Also for future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this a valid xml? I don't think it is

but anyway:

```
<?php
$test = <<<EOT
    <root>
       <Property>
          <Name>TaskId</Name>
          <Value>12345</Value>
       </Property>

       <Property>
          <Name>TaskName</Name>
          <Value>Task1</Value>
       </Property>

       <Property>
          <Name>TaskId</Name>
          <Value>6789</Value>
       </Property>

       <Property>
          <Name>TaskName</Name>
          <Value>Task2</Value>
       </Property>
    </root>
    EOT;

    $document = @DOMDocument::loadXML($test);

    $xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

    $task_id_elements = $xpath->query('//Property//Name[text()="TaskId"]/following-sibling::*');

    $task_ids = array();
    foreach ($task_id_elements as $task_id_element) {
       $task_ids[] = $task_id_element->nodeValue;
    }

    echo implode(" ",$task_ids);
```

Comment: <ArrayOfObject xmlns=""><Object><Properties><Property><Name>TaskId</Name><Value>5830.1</Value></Property><Property><Name>Name</Name><Value>My Task11</Value></Property><Property><Name>State</Name><Value>Finished</Value></Property><Property><Name>CommandLine</Name><Value>md %DATA_DIR%</Value></Property><Property><Name>ExitCode</Name><Value>0</Value></Property><Property><Name>ParentJobId</Name><Value>5830</Value></Property><Property><Name>JobTaskId</Name><Value>1</Value></Property><Property><Name>InstanceId</Name><Value>0</Value></Property></Properties></Object></ArrayOfObject>

Comment: This is the complete xml. I have multiple objects. In this example. I have posted only one example.

Answer (score 0):

```
$objectList = $doc->getElementsByTagName('Object');

for ($o=0;$o<$objectList->length;$o++) 
{
$objectNode = $objectList->item($o);

$properyList = $objectNode->getElementsByTagName('Property');
for ($p=0;$p<$properyList->length;$p++) 
  {
    $propertyNode = $properyList->item($p); 
    $name =  $propertyNode->getElementsByTagName('Name')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $value = $propertyNode->getElementsByTagName('Value')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $d[$name] = $value;
  }     
$task_data[] = $d;
unset($d);
}

foreach ($task_data as $td)
{
echo $td["TaskId"].": ".$td["State"]."<br/>"; 
}
```

Another way and This works! :)